# AngularJS Rest Service - Not displaying Json data in table

Tags: angularjs, json, rest

index.html is as below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Batch Job Data</title>
<link href="css/angular-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="BatchJobApp" >

<div class="container">
<div class="left"><h2><i>Angular JS + Rest + batch /i> </h2></div>
<div class="left" ng-controller="BatchJobController">
<h2>Batch Job Data</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Job Instance ID</th>
    <th>Version</th>
    <th>Job Name</th>
     <th>Job Key</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="batchjob in batchjobs">
    <td>{{ batchjob.jobInstanceId }}</td>
    <td>{{ batchjob.version }}</td>
    <td>{{ batchjob.jobName }}</td>
    <td>{{ batchjob.jobKey }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>  
<script src="webjars/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my App.js is as below -

```
var app = angular.module('BatchJobApp', ['BatchJobApp.controllers', 'BatchJobApp.services' ]);
'use strict';

app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
                  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                    $routeProvider
                      .when('/batch', {templateUrl: 'templates/home.html', controller: 'BatchJobController'});
                      .otherwise({redirectTo: '/batch'})
}]);
```

my controllers.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('BatchJobApp.controllers', [])
.controller('BatchJobController', ['$scope', 'BatchJobService', function($scope, BatchJobService) {

$scope.$apply();
  console.log($scope.batchjobs);
alert("************** In controller js");

  BatchJobService.getBatch(function(data) {
    $scope.batchjobs = data;
  console.log('Successful Transaction');
});
console.log('Failed Transaction');

}]);
```

my services.js is as

```
angular.module('BatchJobApp')
              .service('BatchJobService', function($http, $location) {
this.getBatch = function() { 
    return $http.get('localhost:88/batchjob');
};

});
```

now my rest service gets data from MySQL database and resides with in the same projects and it works fine I get result back something like when I run "localhost:88/batchjob" -

[{"jobInstanceId":0,"version":0.0,"jobName":"XXXX.job","jobKey":"77b72e46b880e4aeb4fd689c835b282d"},
{"jobInstanceId":20,"version":0.0,"jobName":"FFFFF.job","jobKey":"f5913a0693c08e24b7fc88a9559ed2bb"}]

But when I run the app using Spring boot - it doesn't displaying the values but displays only Text as {{ batchjob.jobInstanceId }} and so no..

Is there any jar or Js that I am missing.... any pointers will help....

my pom.xml is as -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is my controller class for rest service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/batchjob")
 public class BatchJobController extends BaseRestController {

@Autowired private BatchJobRepository batchJobRepository;

@RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<BatchJob> batchJobData() {
    return  batchJobRepository.findAll();
 } }
```

Comment: Any errors when you try to run the app using Spring boot?

Comment: Any errors in the js console of your browser?

Answer (score 0):

So there is a bunch of stuff that is wrong. 
To start off what $http returns is a promise so the 'then' function is not param of your service this :

```
BatchJobService.getBatch(function(data) {
    $scope.batchjobs = data;
  console.log('Successful Transaction');
});
```

should be :

```
BatchJobService.getBatch().then(function(response){
    $scope.batchjobs = response.data;
    console.log('Successful Transaction json data',data);
});
```

Second:

Your app.js file references a home.html file in template wich you are leaving no space for it. To do so you must put an ng-view if you choose to use the ngRoute module which you are currently not loading in your app.js file

My advice is to take a look at the angular tutorial to grasp the basic concepts https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial.

On the other hand to fix your current problem you should:

a) add the ngRoute module as a dependency in your app.js
b) Move the div with the ng-controller to the home.html in the template directory
c) add an ng-view in place of the ng-controller div

d) Check the js console for errors and the network tab to check everything is being brought as you expect it.

If I were you just for testing purposes I whould try with the '/' route instead of '/batch' so that spring-boot returns the index.html by default and you can check both the console and the network tab

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tired adding it.. still same result :(

Answer (score 0):

$http.get() return a promise, so try to replace:

```
BatchJobService.getBatch(function(data) {
    $scope.batchjobs = data;
}
```

by:

```
BatchJobService.getBatch.success(function(data) {
    $scope.batchjobs = data;
})
```

and check the js console if it doesn't work...